# How to get this jQueryUI button to be the same size as a button created with a custom CSS style?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

There are two buttons here:

http://jsfiddle.net/fintiblick/g48EL/3/

1. The first `myStyle` uses two custom CSS styles: `mybutton` and `mywidth`.
2. The second button `jqueryui` has
   styles defined by the jQuery UI
   stylesheet and then the button is
   invoked in the JavaScript section
   using:

:

```
jQuery("#dosubmit2").button(
{
    icons: 
    {
        secondary: "ui-icon-search"
    },
    text: false
});
```

**You will notice two problems here if you "Run" the sample.**

(1) I need the jQuery button to always be the exact same width and height as the same button defined using the `.mybutton` style. When run (in Chrome) however, the **`mystyle`** button is **73x42** and the **`jqueryui`** button is **67x42**. How can I ensure that the jQuery UI button always appears with the same size dimensions as buttons using the custom style (`.mybutton`)?

(2) Another less important issue has to do with the fact that the jQuery UI button definition says `text = false` and yet the button text is showing despite that.

Answer (score 2):

Both buttons have dynamic width, basically that is all. They have dynamic width, so their width is based on their content:

- they have different content
- they have a different `font-family`

If you want them to be the same size, specify a `width` on both.

Comment: I updated the example so that they have the same content. What I'm trying to do is update my entire site away from custom styles to the jQuery UI styles. So far, this is causing problems because the elements with the jQuery UI styles applied to them have different sizes than the elements already in place - and therefore this changes the position of the original elements so that they don't fit inside their CSS "boxes". So if I go with your suggestion, I would have to apply a specific width to each element across the site which would be a large task. Instead I was hoping to use a CSS class.

Comment: Have you checked the font-family? When I set them to have the same content, it seems like that's the only difference.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't achieve your desired effect using the [ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) then you can always customize the jQuery UI CSS manually. You will probably find all you need to know here:

- http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#theming
- http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming
- http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming/API
- http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming/CustomThemes

You don't have to use any default CSS that comes with jQuery UI if it doesn't fit your existing design or if you already have styles for buttons that you are satisfied with. The links above will show you which CSS classes are used by jQuery UI buttons and other widgets. You can define those classes yourself.